# Homography of projective space is projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have two questions:

1. Let $V$ be a projective subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$, and let $\gamma$ be a homography on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Prove that $\gamma (V)$ is a projective subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$.
2. Let $V,W$ be two projective subspaces of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $d$ for some $d<n$. Prove that there is a homography $\gamma$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $\gamma (V)=W$.

I know that a bijection of $\mathbb{P}(E)$ induced by an element $u$ in $GL(E)$ is called homography. If $\overline{F}$ is a projective subspace of dimension $d$ in $\mathbb{P}(E)$ and $\overline{u}$ is a homography, then $\overline{u}(\overline{F})=\overline{(u(F)}$: the image of $\overline{F}$ is a projective subspace of dimension $d$. Also, homographies are automorphisms of projective spaces so that two projective subspaces $V,W$ are equivalent if there exists $\gamma :\mathbb{P}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ homography such that $\gamma (V)=W$.

But I don't know how to use this information to answer the two questions above. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any helpful insight or hint?